# IIS 7.5 - why Googlebot receive 500 internal server error from Website?

Tags: iis, asp.net, iis-7.5

I have a problem: when googlebot come to website pages where is login form - it reveice error from site ("ureachable" in webmaster tools).

This error is N500

- HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
- Cache-Control: private
- Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
- Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
- X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
- X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
- Date: Sat, 11 Feb 2012 07:56:20 GMT
- Content-Length: 4855

When googlebot visit pages without login form - it receive ok (status 200)

When I visit website page through browers - everything is ok in all pages (with login forms and with it).

My system:

- Windows Web Server 2008 R2 (x64)
- Application pools: ASP.NET 4 - Managed pipeline mode: "Integrated"
- ISAPI and CGI Restrictions: ASP.NET 4.0.30313 (32-bit): Allowed
- IIS 7.5

I have only one version ASP.NET

Web.config (part):

```
<anonymousIdentification enabled="true" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms 
    cookieless="UseCookies" 
    defaultUrl="Default.aspx" 
    loginUrl="~/AccessDenied.aspx" 
    name="GSFORMAUTH" 
    protection="All" 
    slidingExpiration="true" 
    timeout="44000">
    </forms>
</authentication>
```

Failed Request tracing log (part) :

```
<failedRequest url="http://mysite.com:80/"
       siteId="1"
       appPoolId="ASP.NET v4.0"
       processId="2956"
       verb="GET"
       remoteUserName=""
       userName=""
       tokenUserName="IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0"
       authenticationType="anonymous"
       activityId="{00000000-0000-0000-5700-0080000000F5}"
       failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
       statusCode="200"
       triggerStatusCode="500"
       timeTaken="4172"
       xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
       >
```

What caused this problem?

Thanks for help, Alex.

Comment: Your CGI application or the application pool is crashing, likely, but there is really no information here that sheds any more light.

Answer (score 1):

Google's Webmaster forums has a little info on it. Basically, there's a Firefox plugin that will let you visit the website AS IF you were Googlebot. You'll see it (errors and all) the way Googlebot does. That should help you figure out what it sees.

http://groups.google.com/group/Google_Webmaster_Help-Indexing/browse_thread/thread/f8ba10ba010b6039 - Forum post

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/ - Link to Firefox plugin

In short, the crawler isn't a browser, and will see your page differently than a standard browser. You can use the plugin above to switch your browser to different user-agent modes, namely Googlebot.

Comment: I look in Mozilla as google bot 2.1 - everything ok. But when I look as bot (google webmaster tools) - i see unreachable status